# How to get the attribute value of a parent element in Xpath if Child element exists?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm new to XPath and not sure how to get the attribute value of a parent element if a specific child element exists.

```
<planet name="Earth" star="Sun">
      <primary>
            <oxygen>20.95%</oxygen>
            <water>70.8%</water>
      </primary>
</planet>
```

What should be my XPath to get the `@name` attribute from the element `<planet>` if the `<oxygen>` element is present within primary?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a predicate to look down the tree. This selects all `planet` elements that have `primary/oxygen` subelements. I added a root element assuming this is buried in a document somewhere.

```
import lxml.etree

doc = lxml.etree.fromstring("""<root>
<planet name="Earth" star="Sun">
      <primary>
            <oxygen>20.95%</oxygen>
            <water>70.8%</water>
      </primary>
</planet>
</root>""")

print(doc.xpath('planet[primary/oxygen]/@name'))
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer depends on you current [XPath axis](http://xmlplease.com/axis). So if your current axis is `<oxygen>` the XPath expression to access the `@name` attribute of the element `<planet>` would be:

```
../../@name
```

Or encapsulated in an XSLT expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../@name" />
```